# Proof of Cartesian product intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C, D$ be sets. 
How to prove $( A \times B ) \cap ( C \times D ) = ( A \cap C ) \times ( B \cap D )$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align*}
(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (C\times D)&\iff (x,y)\in A\times B\text{ and }(x,y)\in C\times D\\\\
&\iff\cdots\;?\\\\
&\iff x\in A\cap C\text{ and }y\in B\cap D\\\\
&\iff(x,y)\in (A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: x element of A and y element of B and x element of C and y element of D
there fore x definitely an element of A intersect C and y definitely an element of B intersect D

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: For a full proof, see the first part of [this answer of mine to another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/377160/11994).